# Hide the default Gigya email share popup on click of the Gigya Share bar email icon

Tags: angularjs, html, gigya

I am using the following code to implement the Set up Gigya share bar:

```
if ($window.gigya) {
        // Step 1: Construct a UserAction object and fill it with data
        var ua = new $window.gigya.socialize.UserAction();
        ua.setLinkBack(articleUrl);
        ua.setTitle($scope.title);
        // Step 2: Define the Share Bar add-on's params object     
        var params = {
            userAction: ua,
            //shareButtons: 'linkedin,twitter,facebook,sina,email', // list of providers
            shareButtons: 'linkedin,twitter,facebook,sina,email',
            containerID: 'share-bar',
            showCounts: 'none',
            deviceType: 'auto',
            cid: '',
            wrap: true,
            operationMode:'multiSelect',
            onShareButtonClicked:function (e) {
              console.log(e);
              console.log(e.shareItem.provider);
                if (e.shareItem.provider == 'email') {
                  var mailString = 'mailto:test@example.com'
                  $window.location.href = mailString;                                  
              }
            }
        };
        // Step 3: Load the Share Bar add-on:
        $window.gigya.socialize.showShareBarUI(params);
    }
```

The above code displays the share bar provided by Gigya.

Now clicking the email option I am trying to open the default client mail (for example outlook). I see that the default email popup also get opened along with the outlook.

How to stop the default UI from opening in this case. I tried all the options but none are working for me.

Can anyone help me to know how to fix this issue.

Answer (score 0):

I don't believe this behavior is supported. By design, the Share add-on, when sharing via email, constructs the actual message on the server using the UserAction passed in the request and then sends it from there. So, even if you got the default UI to not populate, how would you be getting the actual share data inside the 3rd party email program?

Comment: As mentioned in my code above I am able to open the outlook but somehow the default view for the email  popup opens before opening the outlook. I tried to use gigya.socialize.hideUI(); to hide the default view onShareButtonClicked event, but still for the first time the popup opens and if I close it then on subsequent requests I don't see opening again and the outlook opens successfully.

Comment: I understand that, however, that is not how the share bar is designed to function. If you do not want to use the native Gigya email share, then why don't you only use it for non-email shares and implement a custom email share button that opens the native browser outside of the ShareBar? Be advised, however, that Gigya analyzes the content of the emails we send for questionable content, i.e., XSS, etc. So, this would not be recommended and not supported.